# Navigate from one war to another JSF through bean

Tags: jsf-2, java-ee-6, myfaces

I have 3 wars in one EAR.
Once user clicks on a link in a page, control goes to bean and business logic decides where user will be navigated. Resulting page can be in any of the three wars.

Also i need requesting URL so that I can navigate user back to requesting page if they decide to click on cancel link.

I can navigate using JSF by defining navigation in faces-config.xml
e.g:

```
<from-view-id>/GeneralInfo.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{registrationBean.goToLogin}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>Success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/LoginInfo.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
```

But this navigation is limited for navigation between pages inside single war.

2nd option is using faces redirect which can redirect even on 3rd party server URL's
e.g: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect('login.xhtml')`

Using 2nd option i cannot retrieve requesting URL using below code

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest().getRequestURL();
```

My question is, Is their any 3rd option where I can navigate to pages into another war(having JSF configuration's) and can also get requesting URL as well.

Let me know if anything else is required.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use JSF navigation cases to go to pages in a different application context. So sending a redirect is the only option. If you'd like to pass additional parameters along with the redirect, then pass them as request query string parameters:

```
String from = request.getRequestURL().toString();
externalContext.redirect("/othercontext/login.xhtml?from=" + URLEncoder.encode(from, "UTF-8"));
```

The other application can then just redirect back as follows:

```
String from = request.getParameter("from");
externalContext.redirect(from);
```